# Is it guaranteed that Complex Float variables will be 8-byte aligned in memory?

Tags: gcc, c99, compiler-optimization, memory-alignment, complex-numbers

In C99 the new complex types were defined. I am trying to understand whether a compiler can take advantage of this knowledge in optimizing memory accesses. Are these objects (`A`-`F`) of type `complex float` guaranteed to be 8-byte aligned in memory?

```
#include "complex.h"
typedef complex float cfloat;

cfloat A;
cfloat B[10];

void func(cfloat C, cfloat *D)
{
    cfloat E;
    cfloat F[10];
}
```

Note that for `D`, the question relates to the object pointed to by `D`, not to the pointer storage itself. And, if that is assumed aligned, how can one be sure that the address passed is of an actual complex and not a cast from another (non 8-aligned) type?

UPDATE 1: I probably answered myself in the last comment regarding the `D` pointer. B/c there is no way to know what address will be assigned to the parameter of the function call, there is no way to guarantee that it will be 8-aligned. This is solvable via the `__builtin_assumed_aligned()` function.

The question is still open for the other variables.

UPDATE 2: I posted a [follow-up question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934987/is-there-a-reason-why-not-to-impose-8-byte-alignment-for-complex-float-type).

Comment: This is really an [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) issue. C is statically typed, so you can't _ensure_ an address points to a variable or object of a particular type.

Comment: Thanks, @BrettHale. Why not make this an answer instead of a comment? The intention of the question is indeed to understand if the standard dictates any alignment for these variables. From your comment I understand that it does not, right? What does it have to do with "statically typed"?

Comment: The C standard has certain guarantees about alignment, packing, padding, etc., for consistent behaviour. The preferred (and often required) alignment of data is typically platform-dependent, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `float complex` is guaranteed to have the same memory layout and alignment as an array of two `float` (§6.2.5).  Exactly what that alignment will be is defined by your compiler or platform.  All you can say for sure is that a `float complex` is *at least as aligned* as a `float`.

> if that is assumed aligned, how can one be sure that the address passed is of an actual complex and not a cast from another (non 8-aligned) type?

If your caller passes you an insufficiently-aligned pointer, that's undefined behavior and a bug in their code (§6.3.2.3).  You don't need to support that (though you may choose to).

Comment: So, this means that there is no guarantee (per the standard) for 8-alignment.

Comment: @ysap: Correct.  There is no guarantee (per the standard) for even 1-byte alignment.

Comment: Thanks. Just posted a follow-up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934987/is-there-a-reason-why-not-to-impose-8-byte-alignment-for-complex-float-type