# Is there a reason why NOT to force 8-byte alignment for complex float type?

Tags: gcc, c99, compiler-optimization, memory-alignment, complex-numbers

This is a follow-up for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928341/is-it-guaranteed-that-complex-float-variables-will-be-8-byte-aligned-in-memory).

We have an implementation of GCC for our embedded architecture. As such we have control over some aspects of the compiler and optimizer. Such aspect may be potentially forcing the 8-byte aligned allocation of complex float objects. Generally speaking, on our architecture we can optimize access to these objects if they are properly aligned, by requiring a single double-load instruction instead of two regular loads.

Just before a round of enhancements and bug fixes, I am trying to figure out if there are good arguments against forcing such alignment when a complex float object is declared. Is there a reason why not to force that?

Comment: I suppose if you're *really* trying to eke out every byte, maybe, since alignment could leave some gaps if things aren't re-arranged?

Comment: @DaveNewton - that's a good point, but not a problem in our case.

Comment: Support both `__attribute((aligned(8)))__` and  `__attribute((aligned(4)))__` for such type, the default being whatever most users want (I say 8).

Comment: @n.m. - thanks. I don't think these attributes apply to local (automatic) variables or to function parameters.

Comment: I think it applies to all variables and structure members. Give it a try. I have no gcc on my smartphone, so I can't :-(

Comment: Ideone says yes to locals, no to function parameters. Perhaps you can just always align them to 8 bytes.