# Is there an O(1) way to separate real and imaginary parts of complex array when passed to pgplot?

Tags: c, arrays, time-complexity, complex-numbers

I have a complex float array in my code that a library generates for me. Consider it is something like this:

```
float _Complex data[N];
```

In order to take it as separate arrays having real and imaginary parts, I iterate over the array and take the values like this:

```
float real[N];
float imag[N];
for (int pt=0;pt<N;pt++) {
  real[pt] = creal(data[pt]);
  imag[pt] = cimag(data[pt]));    
}
```

But this is really inefficient as this is a `O(N)` operation in terms of both execution time and space. I want to know if the arrays can be separated using some pointer arithmetic so that the execution time and memory use is reduced?

I need to plot the real and imaginary values separately. My plotting library, PGPLOT, requires an array of values to be sent to it so I cannot use the complex array "in place".

Comment: No, you're going to need to work with them in-place if you want O(1).

Comment: I cannot use them inplace. edited the question.

Comment: First of all, is this really a C question, or a C++ question? What plotting library are you talking about? Second of all, are you sure that there's no way to pass the array stride to the plotting library? Perhaps your plotting library could be modified to accept a stride, then you wouldn't have to copy the data at all.

Comment: I am using PGPLOT library for plotting and yeah this is a C question

Comment: I guess the lesson for the next question is: abstracting out the details is only helpful to a point. Here, your problem was that you presupposed a solution to a problem without telling us what the problem was. The problem was indeed very much related to the PGPLOT library and had nothing much to do with complexity theory :)

Comment: @KubaOber C++ does not have _Complex

Comment: @MattMcNabb Word. Missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
float _Complex data[N];
```

We know that:

```
float *ptr = (float *) data;
ptr[2 * n + 0] <- real part.
ptr[2 * n + 1] <- imaginary part.
```

We can see some rationalization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928341/is-it-guaranteed-that-complex-float-variables-will-be-8-byte-aligned-in-memory). Basically, a `float _Complex` will have the same memory layout as `float[2]`.

Modifying this such that all of the reals are contiguous would require a similar operation to your `O(n)` version mentioned in the question.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. I have to deal with the delay then.Anyway Thanks for the reply..

Comment: I'm not 100% sure whether this has well-defined behavior, but it's the closest thing to a solution...

Comment: @KubaOber I am using PGPLOT to plot these as that is the standard library to be used for the project. I dont think it provides a way to stride as it is just a wrapper for a age-old fortran plotting library.

Answer (score 5):

The `pgplot` library offers a strideless interface to draw marker arrays:

```
void cpgpt(int n, const float *xpts, const float *ypts, int symbol);
```

But this is just a thin wrapper around individual calls to `cpgpt1`. Thus, it's easy enough to add a stride-taking interface:

```
void cpgpts(int n, int stride, const float *xpts, const float *ypts, int symbol) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cpgpt1(*xpts, *ypts, symbol);
    xpts += stride;
    ypts += stride;
  }
}
```

Of course you'll want to write wrappers around the ugliness of complex-to-float casting. For example:

```
void cpgptsc(int n, const float _Complex *pts, int symbol) {
  cpgpts(n, 2, (const float*)pts, ((const float*)pts)+1, symbol);
}
```

Example:

```
// Plot the data as symbols on the Re-Im plane
cpgptsc(count, data, symbol);
```

You can similarly reimplement the `cpgline`:

```
void cpglines(int n, int stride, const float *xpts, const float *ypts, int symbol) {
  cpgmove(*xpts, *ypts);
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++ i) {
    xpts += stride;
    ypts += stride;
    cpgdraw(*xpts, *ypts);
  }
}

void cpglinesc(int n, const float _Complex *pts, int symbol) {
  cpglines(n, 2, (const float*)pts, ((const float*)pts)+1, symbol);
}
```

Example:

```
// Plot the data as lines on the Re-Im plane
cpglinesc(count, data);
```

If you're only plotting the single component (either real or imaginary), it's similarly simple to create a reasonable wrapper for it:

```
void cpglinesx(int n, int stride, float dx, float x0, const float *ypts) {
  cpgmove(x0, *ypts);
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++ i) {
    x0 += dx;
    ypts += stride;
    cpgdraw(x0, *ypts);
  }
}

void cpglinesxre(int n, float dx, float x0, const float _Complex *pts) {
  cpglinesx(n, 2, dx, x0, (const float*)pts);
}

void cpglinesxim(int n, float dx, float x0, const float _Complex *pts) {
  cpglinesx(n, 2, dx, x0, ((const float*)pts)+1);
}
```

Then, to plot, say, the imaginary component starting at x=0, with increment of 1.0, you'd do:

```
// Plot the imaginary coordinates of all the data
cpglinesxim(count, 1.0, 0.0, data);
```

Comment: I cant accept your answer because this is a bit off the title of the question. but really this saved my life today thanks a lot. I wish I could do a +100.

Comment: @VivekVK Of course it's off the title, because your title presupposed a solution. You were looking for something that you didn't even need to find :) Good luck on your project. I just visited NRAO at Green Bank a couple of weeks ago, although only to enjoy the views and the enormity of it :) Radioastronomy is seriously cool (this refers to your profile pic in front of I imagine a radiotelescope of some sort) :)

Comment: @VivekVK Simple solution ... fix your title and then accept.

Comment: @KubaOber that is the Molonglo Synthesis telescope in Australia :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of length N of input, there really isn't an O(1) algorithm to go through all of it.

Comment: what I was expecting was that if the complex library stores it as two arrays, there might be a way to get a pointer to the first element to the real and imaginary parts of the array and access it henceforth.

Comment: @VivekVK Storing complex numbers as separate real and imaginary parts across arrays is a surefire way to effectively halve your CPU's cache size. No sane implementation would do such a thing. Your question presupposes something that simply isn't there.

Comment: @VivekVK: There's no way to get contiguous arrays of the parts in O(1)

Comment: C explicitly requires that the real and imaginary parts are stored adjacently with representations matching the corresponding real floating-point type. The only time an implementation could ignore this requirement is when the compiler can see all uses of the address of the object and can prove that an alternate storage format could not be observed by the program.